# Designing form with multiple rows and a button in css

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, styled-components

I am using ReactJS and CSS and trying to create a form with multiple rows and a button.

I can't figure out the CSS that will make it work. I have tried to do it with flexbox but it was too hare to manage the inputs and the button.

I believe grid is the solution but I haven't managed to find the correct layout yet...

Btw the form is in Hebrew so I am also trying to make the inputs go from right to left.
If Hebrew is strange to you, just try to look at it as symbols :)

I am adding Images with details and the relevant code snippets.

Thanks in advance!

```
import React from "react";
import FormInput from "../FormInput/FormInput";
import {
  ButtonContainer,
  DetailsContainer,
  StaticDetailsContainer,
  FormContainer
} from "../Details/Details-styles";
import staticDetails from "../../assets/details-static.png";

class Details extends React.Component {
  state = {
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
    email: "",
    phone: ""
  };

  handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("handling submit");
    const { email, phone, firstName, lastName } = this.state;
    //submit to server
  };

  handleChange = event => {
    const { value, name } = event.target;
    this.setState({ [name]: value });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <DetailsContainer>
        <StaticDetailsContainer src={staticDetails} />
        <FormContainer>
          <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <FormInput
              name="lastName"
              type={"text"}
              placeholder="שם משפחה"
              value={this.state.lastName}
              handleChange={this.handleChange}
            />
            <FormInput
              name="firstName"
              type="text"
              placeholder={"שם פרטי"}
              value={this.state.firstName}
              handleChange={this.handleChange}
            />
            <FormInput
              name="phone"
              type="phone"
              placeholder={"טלפון"}
              value={this.state.phone}
              handleChange={this.handleChange}
            />
            <FormInput
              name="email"
              type="email"
              placeholder={'דוא"ל'}
              value={this.state.email}
              handleChange={this.handleChange}
            />
            <ButtonContainer type="submit">תאם לי שיעור</ButtonContainer>
          </form>
        </FormContainer>
      </DetailsContainer>
    );
  }
}

export default Details;
```

```
import styled from "styled-components";

export const DetailsContainer = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 50%;

  @media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    width: 100%;
  }
`;

export const StaticDetailsContainer = styled.img`
  width: 100%;
`;

export const FormContainer = styled.div`
  display: flex;
`;

export const ButtonContainer = styled.button`
  width: 25%;
  height: 5vh;
  background-color: #2eaaa7;
  margin: auto;
  color: white;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 26px;
  border: none;

  @media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    font-size: 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
`;
```

This is how it supposed to be:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use this **CSS Grid Layout**:

```css
.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 10px;
}
.span-row-2{grid-row: span 2 / auto;}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="span-row-2">Item 1</div>
  <div>Item 2</div>
  <div>Item 3</div>
  <div>Item 4</div>
  <div>Item 5</div>
</div>
```

There is a cool website called **[cssgr.id](https://cssgr.id)** where you can design CSS Grid Layouts visually.

Hope it works for you!